element-wise comparison (-1/0/1) of collections/IEnumerables, not using default element comparison
Is there some built-in for comparing collections/IEnumerables element-wise with the possibility to choose comparison for the elements (in case one does not want the default comparison)?
I am not interested in SequenceEquals. I need a Compare/CompareTo method that returns -1/0/1.
Use case: I need to implement CompareTo from IComparable<> for my custom class. This class has a property of type IReadOnlyCollection<string>. I want to compare two such collections elementwise, but not by default string comparison because that is not lexicographic. string.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.Ordinal) does what I need, I guess StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(string1, string2) as well.
So I am basically looking for some Comparer doing the element-wise thing that allows me to write SoughtComparer.Compare(coll1, coll2, StringComparer.Ordinal). Is there such a comparer, or some other one-liner doing the same?
I need it to work for .NET 4.8, .NET 4.8.1, .NET 6.0, and .NET 8.0.
So the semantics of the one-liner should be like this (for T=string and c=StringComparer.Ordinal:
public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> l1, IEnumerable<T> l2, IComparer<T> c)
{
    var l1Enum = l1.GetEnumerator();
    var l2Enum = l2.GetEnumerator();
    var l1HasNext = l1Enum.MoveNext();
    var l2HasNext = l2Enum.MoveNext();
    while (l1HasNext && l2HasNext)
    {
        var entryComparison = c.Compare(l1Enum.Current, l2Enum.Current);
        if (entryComparison != 0)
            return entryComparison;
        l1HasNext = l1Enum.MoveNext();
        l2HasNext = l2Enum.MoveNext();
    }
    if (!l1HasNext)
        return l2HasNext ? -1 : 0;
    return 1;
}

I assume that since that approach is so generic (and it is exactly what string comparers do, considering a string as a list of char), the C# team has implemented that already. And I prefer not to reinvent the wheel and rather use little code than much code. But I cannot find it anywhere.

Can you explain the logic when the result would be -1 or 1? It's easy enough to determine when two collections are equivalent (SequenceEquals with an IEqualityComparer<TSource> overload), but what happens if the lists are different lengths?

Isn't StringComparer.Ordinal the very comparer you are looking for?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes No, I want to compare not two strings but two IReadOnlyCollection<string>s.

@gunr2171 See code in my question.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91514

There's no such routine within standard library, but you can implement it.
Let's come to terms:

Sequence s1 > s2 if s1[k] > s2[k] and s1[i] == s2[i] for all i = 0..k-1
Sequence s1 > s2 if s1[i] == s2[i] for all i and Length(s1) > Length(s2)
Sequence s1 == s2 if and only if Length(s1) == Length(s2) and s1[i] == s2[i] for all i

If it's your task then
public static int MyCompare<T>(IEnumerable<T>? left, 
                               IEnumerable<T>? right, 
                               IComparer<T>? comparer) {
  comparer ??= Comparer<T>.Default;

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(
    $"{typeof(T).Name} doesn't implement IComparable<{typeof(T).Name}>");

  if (left is null) // let null be less any not-null sequence
    return right is null ? 0 : -1;
  if (right is null)
    return 1;

  using var leftEn = left.GetEnumerator();
  using var rightEn = right.GetEnumerator();

  while (true) {
    bool leftMove = leftEn.MoveNext();
    bool rightMove = rightEn.MoveNext();

    if (leftMove && rightMove) {
      int result = comparer.Compare(leftEn.Current, rightEn.Current);

      if (result != 0)
        return Math.Sign(result); // if you insist on +1 and -1
    }
    else if (!leftMove)
      return rightMove ? -1 : 0;
    else if (!rightMove)
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

and overload for comparable types:
public static int MyCompare<T>(IEnumerable<T>? left, IEnumerable<T>? right) 
  where T : IComparable<T> =>
    MyCompare<T>(left, right, default);

Examples:
int[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
int[] b = [1, 7, 3];

// -1 since 1 == 1, but 2 < 7
Console.Write(MyCompare(a, b));


What about arrays like [1,3,2] and [3,2,1]

@Michał Turczyn: [1, 3, 2] < [3, 2, 1] since the very first item of the 1st array is less than 1st item of the second: 1 < 3 so the output is -1. I compare 1st items, and if they are equal 2nd items etc.
